# Can't detect collide with opposite player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a ray cast for the snake to detect whether he collided with himself, food or the enemy, it works fine with the food and himself but when he collides with the enemy he just passes through.

This is the code that detects the collisions:

```
RaycastHit hit;

if (Physics.Raycast(HeadBone.position, HeadBone.right, out hit, 1))
{
    if (hit.transform.tag == "Player")
    {
        NetworkManager.instance.GetComponent<NetworkManager>().CommadSuicide(transform.name);
        return;
    }
    else if (hit.transform.tag == "Enemy")
    {
        NetworkManager.instance.GetComponent<NetworkManager>().KillTarget(hit.transform.name);
    }
    else if (hit.transform.tag == "Food")
    {
        Eat(hit.transform.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the tag on the enemy is in fact `Enemy`, that will often trip me up as I forget to set the tag. If that's not the issue, go through in the debugger and see if it's even running that line inside the if statement

Comment: @TJWolschon i did and it's the right tag.

Comment: Please use the debug tool debug and check that the ray is getting any collision, check the mask you are passing to the function... Also check that the other objects have an collider.

Comment: If that if statement for the enemy is acutally met (put a Debug.Log for a simple check), there has to be a problem within `KillTarget`. Just to make sure though, the enemies do have a collider/trigger?

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a return statement

If you put return statement in if, while or for statement then it may or may not return value. If it will not go inside these statements then also that method should return some value ( that could be null). To ensure that, the compiler will force you to write this return statement which is after if, while or for.

But if you write if / else block and each one of them is having a return in it then the compiler knows that either if or else will get execute and method will return a value. So this time compiler will not force you.

```
    RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(HeadBone.position, HeadBone.right, out hit, 1))
        {
            if (hit.transform.tag == "Player")
            {
                NetworkManager.instance.GetComponent<NetworkManager>().CommadSuicide(transform.name);
                return;
            }

            else if (hit.transform.tag == "Enemy")
            {
                NetworkManager.instance.GetComponent<NetworkManager>().KillTarget(hit.transform.name);
                return;
            }

            else if (hit.transform.tag == "Food")
            {
                Eat(hit.transform.gameObject);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I don't think that would help though? After it runs the line in the if statement, it will just drop out of the method, so adding the return is redundant.

Comment: I think it would help because if he doesn't put a return after hitting the enemy it will just continue.

Comment: It will leave the if/else block and continue in the method if there's any other code, but from what we've been shown, there isn't any other code. Therefore, it will automatically return void without having to explicitly tell it to.

Comment: I know what you mean but then the return by the player is also redundant? Then I don't know what the problem is. I was just trying to help.

Comment: I agree, that the original return is redundant, given the information we currently have. I still have no clue what the actual issue is though, we need more info from OP.

Comment: @Fabian i don't think the return has nothing to do because it works fine with the tag "player"

Comment: @TJWolschon i checked the tag in the editor in the debug, and there is another bit of code but everything works fine but this simple line of code

Comment: @seifeldin did you add the return statement, just for a test purpose?

Comment: @Fabian I think that the return is useless in all ways, also in the OP

Comment: @seifeldin Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green checkmark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.